# External libraries for mule deployment

Tags: esb, mule

I have a mule app that I developed (and checked) on Eclipse's Mule IDE, and one of the components in it is using the external Microsoft JDBC SQL Server Driver class. Everything runs just fine on the Eclipse server but when I try to deploy and run the app from the command line (Mule standalone server/service) - I have a `classnotfound` exception for that same Microsoft JDBC driver.

How can I include that driver in my deployment program so that I can run without Eclipse?

I thought that by adding the external jar to the Eclipse project, it would load that class into the Mule deployment (app) directory. But I was wrong.

What can be done about this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the [Mule deployment model specs](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/MULE3USER/Application+Format), you application JARs must be placed in a /lib directory in the archive. Is it the case?

If yes and still not working, then it is possible that these JARs are needed by Mule itself (as opposed to just your application) and therefore these JARs must be placed in MULE_HOME/lib/user (so they're picked by Mule's classloader instead of your application-specific classloader).